# responsive div acting weird in iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, wordpress, ipad, media-queries, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently working on a website using WordPress with a child theme. On the product page, I am using Advanced Custom Field with lightbox for product catalogue (not a store). I am struggled to figured out why the product image & text container appear as a full width on iPad and iPhone. When I resized the desktop browser to iPad size and it show 4 columns and 2 columns on iPhone size. Any help would be appreciate!

http://kampshydrangea.com/wordpress/products/

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

you are using meta tag viewport (`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1">`), read about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag